# spring boot jar missing project dependencies

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependencies

I have a Spring Boot project that is built using Gradle.  It has compile dependencies on other projects.  All the projects are mentioned via "includeFlat" in a settings.gradle file in a master project.

My problem: the boot ("fat") jar that is generated by the build omits the project dependencies.

Here's the project structure:

```
master
   (no source)
   build.gradle  - applies 'Eclipse' plugin (but not Java)
   settings.gradle -- has 'includeFlat' for projectA, projectB
projectA
   src/main/java/...
   build.gradle
projectB
    src/main/java/...
    build.gradle  -- see below
```

The build.gradle for projectB looks roughly like this:

```
buildscript 
{
    repositories 
    {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies
    {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.1.RELEASE")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

jar 
{
    baseName = 'xxx'
    version =  '0.1.0'
}

repositories 
{
    mavenCentral()
}

jar {
    enabled = true
}

dependencies 
{
    compile project(":projectA")
}
```

"gradle build" on projectB generates both a regular and a boot jar. I expect the boot jar to include the classes from ":projectA" -- but they are missing.

Other than that, both projects build and run properly, whether built individually or via the master project.